# I need a sql statement in java that finds an average with a where clause and returns value

Tags: java, sql, average

So far my code is:

```
try{

    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT AVG(WPM) FROM Attempts WHERE Username = ('" + Login.loginUsername + "');

    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    int add1 = rs.getInt("AVG(WPM)");

        System.out.println("avg temp is " + add1);
    }

    catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
```

my database is set up like so:

- (PK) 'AttemptID'  Integer    AutoIncrement
- 'WPM'        Integer
- (FK) 'Username'   Varchar(45)

I want it to return average WPM based on each username. If I change the line

```
int add1 = rs.getInt("AVG(WPM)");
```

to

```
String add1 = rs.getString("AVG(WPM)");
```

there is no difference. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `double add1 = rs.getDouble(1);`

Explanaition: `rs.get...(1)` gets the column based on the column index, not based on the name of the column. The database might change this when using functions in your select. Also, use double instead of int as AVG returns a double.

Comment: andre forsbaerg it still gives the same message 
'Before start of result set'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you forget the statement **rs.next()**...

Answer (score 0):

1. your sql have SQL injection ..
2. AVG function result maybe to float or double .

**float f = rs.getFloat(1);//**

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need to add a group by clause to your select statement.  Your select statement would then read: select avg(WPD) from Attempts group by Usename where Username = ...  That should correctly calculate the average WPD per user.  Since you are using average I would think that the value returned is likely a double.  In that case you should use rs.getDouble.  Only a single value is selected in the query so you can use the index of the column to access it.  The call will then be rs.getDouble(0).  I hope you find this answer helpful.

Good luck,
Nikolai